# Filter .csv data based on user input and refresh d3.js map

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, filter, bind

I am a d3.js noob and have been able to hack together a map for a project but now I'm stuck. I want to refresh the map based on user input/selection on any combination of five dimensions. Based on the user input, I want my code to filter to only the rows of data that meet the selected criteria, summarize the headcount for that geographic location and refresh the map. Due to various project constraints, I have to use .csv or .json as my data source. I know I can switch data sources and refresh the map based on user input, but due to the number of possible selection combinations that solution isn't feasible for my project. I think I'm close, but I'm not sure how to cross the finish line. I have stored the user selections in variables, created a d3.nest of my data and have been able to create d3.sums on a specified d3.nest key.

I think I've found posts that answer my questions but I'm too much of a noob to understand how to synthesize the relevant information for my project. What I need to do is dynamically create the d3.nest and d3.sum based on user-input, but I don't know how to link my user-selection variables to my function that creates the nest & sum. I'd like to refresh the map and data each time the user makes a selection, but I'd be open to putting a button on the screen that refreshes the data if that's easier. Here is a screenshot of my map [map sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZk7n.jpg).

Here are the relevant sections of my code:

```
        // ######################################################################
    // BUILD THE MAP, PLOT THE DATA AND SIZE THE BUBBLES
    // ######################################################################

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .center([0, 0])
        .scale(225)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);

    // LOAD THE GEOJSON DATA FOR THE MAP
    // ---------------------------------
    d3.json("world-50m.json", function ready(error, world) {

        g.selectAll('path')
            .data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features)
            .enter().append('path')
            .attr("id", function(d) {
                return d.properties.abbreviation;
            })
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("fill", "#ffcc99")
            .attr("stroke", "#ffffff")
            .on("click", clicked);

        // LOAD THE CSV DATA TO POPULATE THE LOCATIONS
        // AND BUBBLE SIZES ON THE MAP
        // -------------------------------------------
        d3.csv("sample_data.csv", function(data) {

            // INCLUDE ONLY THOSE ROWS OF DATA WITH
            // LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE VALUES AND CONVERT
            // CSV DATA INTO NUMERIC VALUES
            // -----------------------------------------
            data = data.filter(function(d, i) {

                if (d.LATITUDE && d.LONGITUDE) {

                    // CONVERT LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE
                    // VALUES FROM CSV FILE TO NUMBERS
                    d.LATITUDE = +d.LATITUDE;
                    d.LONGITUDE = +d.LONGITUDE;

                    // CONVERT HEADCOUNT VALUES FROM
                    // CSV FILE TO NUMBERS
                    d.HEADCOUNT = +Math.round((d.HEADCOUNT) * 1) / 1;

                    // CALCULATE THE POSITION OF THE
                    // HEADCOUNT DATA POINT WITHIN
                    // THE PROJECTION
                    d.position = projection([
                        d.LONGITUDE, d.LATITUDE
                    ]);

                    return true;
                }
            });

            // DRAW THE CIRCLES ON THE MAP AND SIZE THEM
            // BASED ON HEADCOUNT
            // -----------------------------------------
            g.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return d.position[0];
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return d.position[1];
                })
                .attr("r", function(d) {
                    return (bubblescale(d.HEADCOUNT));
                })
                .attr("fill", "#b300b3")
                .attr("fill-opacity", "0.7")
                .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                    div.transition()
                        .duration(200)
                        .style("opacity", .9);
                    div.html(d.HEADCOUNT + " people in " + d.GEOCODE_LOCATION)
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
                })
                .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                    div.transition()
                        .duration(500)
                        .style("opacity", 0);;
                });
        });

    });

    // ######################################################################
    // NESTING, FILTERING AND SUMMARIZING DATA
    // ######################################################################

    d3.csv("sample_data.csv", function(csv) {

        var data_nest = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) {
                return d.GEOCODE_LOCATION;
            })
    .key(function(d) {
                return d.CATEGORY1;
            })
            .key(function(d) {
                return d.CATEGORY2;
            })
            .key(function(d) {
                return d.CATEGORY3;
            })
            .key(function(d) {
                return d.TYPE1;
            })
            .key(function(d) {
                return d.TYPE2;
            })
            .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
            .entries(csv);
        console.log(data_nest);

        var data_sums = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) {
                return d.GEOCODE_LOCATION;
            })
    .key(function(d) {
                return d.LONGITUDE;
            })
    .key(function(d) {
                return d.LATITUDE;
            })
            .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
            .rollup(function(d) {
                return {
                    headcount: d3.sum(d, function(g) {
                        return +g.HEADCOUNT;
                    })
                };
            })
            .entries(csv);
        console.log(data_sums);

    });

    // ######################################################################
    // POPULATE THE FIVE MENU LISTS
    // ######################################################################

    function load_menus() {
        d3.csv("category1.csv", function(error, data_c1) {

            var select = d3.select("#c1_div")
                .append("div")
                .append("select")

            select
                .on("change", function(d) {
                    var selected_c1 = d3.select(this).property("value");
                    alert(value);
                });

            select.selectAll("option")
                .data(data_c1)
                .enter()
                .append("option")
                .attr("value", function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                });
        });

        d3.csv("category2.csv", function(error, data_c2) {

            var select = d3.select("#c2_div")
                .append("div")
                .append("select")

            select
                .on("change", function(d) {
                    var selected_c2 = d3.select(this).property("value");
                    alert(value);
                });

            select.selectAll("option")
                .data(data_c2)
                .enter()
                .append("option")
                .attr("value", function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                });
        });

        d3.csv("category3.csv", function(error, data_c3) {

            var select = d3.select("#c3_div")
                .append("div")
                .append("select")

            select
                .on("change", function(d) {
                    var selected_c3 = d3.select(this).property("value");
                    alert(value);
                });

            select.selectAll("option")
                .data(data_c3)
                .enter()
                .append("option")
                .attr("value", function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                });
        });

        d3.csv("type1.csv", function(error, data_t1) {
            var select = d3.select("#t1_div")
                .append("div")
                .append("select")

            select
                .on("change", function(d) {
                    var selected_t1 = d3.select(this).property("value");
                    alert(value);
                });

            select.selectAll("option")
                .data(data_t1)
                .enter()
                .append("option")
                .attr("value", function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                });
        });

        d3.csv("type2.csv", function(error, data_t2) {
            var select = d3.select("#t2_div")
                .append("div")
                .append("select")

            select
                .on("change", function(d) {
                    var selected_t2 = d3.select(this).property("value");
                    alert(value);
                });

            select.selectAll("option")
                .data(data_t2)
                .enter()
                .append("option")
                .attr("value", function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                });
        });
    }

    window.onload = load_menus;

    // ######################################################################
    // FILTER DATA BASED ON USER SELECTION - NOT WORKING
    // ######################################################################

    function filter_data() {
        d3.csv("map_data.csv", function(error, data) {
            var filterCategory1 = selected_c1;
            var filterCategory2 = selected_c2;
            var filterCategory3 = selected_c3;
            var filterType1 = selected_t1;
            var filterType2 = selected_t2;

            var filtered_data = data.filter(function(d) {
                return d.CATEGORY1 == filterCategory1;
            })
        });
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of my sample data:

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kn0X.jpg)

I've been searching online and in books for over a week now and have neither found other D3 examples of what I'm trying to do nor answers to my data binding, filtering and aggregation questions.

Any help is appreciated. I promise I'll pay it forward when I have the skillz to do so. If I can get this working I'll happily post my full solution on github and link to it from this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your problem here is not specifically D3, but JavaScript scope.

When you write something like:

```
 d3.csv("category1.csv", function(error, data_c1) {

        var select = d3.select("#c1_div")
            .append("div")
            .append("select")

        select
            .on("change", function(d) {
                var selected_c1 = d3.select(this).property("value");
                alert(value);
            });
```

That variable `selected_c1` exists only inside the anonymous function that contains it. A local variable can only be used inside the function where it is defined. It is hidden from other functions and other scripting code (see here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp).

Thus, when you try to use it later, inside `filter_data()`, it's not available.

A solution here is passing `selected_c1` and all the other 4 variables to `filter_data` as an argument. It could be something like this:

```
 d3.csv("category1.csv", function(error, data_c1) {

        var select = d3.select("#c1_div")
            .append("div")
            .append("select")

        select
            .on("change", function(d) {
                var selected_c1 = d3.select(this).property("value");
                filter_data(selected_c1);
            });
```

And then, change your `filter_data()` parameter:

```
function filter_data(selection) {
    d3.csv("map_data.csv", function(error, data) {

        var filtered_data = data.filter(function(d) {
            return d.CATEGORY1 == selection;
        })
    });
}
```

Keep in mind that despite you successfully passed `selected_c1` to `filter_data()`, you now face the same problem again: `var filtered_data` exists only inside `filter_data`, and you have 2 options to pass it to your drawing function:

1. Making it global;
2. Passing it as an argument.

This is just a partial answer, you still have some hard work ahead putting all this together.

Comment: Thanks for the response Gerardo!  I will give this a try.  Your time is very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks again Gerardo for your input.  I still have a lot to do, but your response pointed me in the right direction.  I'm able to store the selected values now and pass them to the necessary function.  My d3.nest and d3.sum functions are being fussy about how I'm passing them the data but once I figure that out I should be well on my way to finishing.  As promised, I will post the final code and sample data on github for anyone else who'd find this type of online functionality helpful.

Comment: No worries. I believe you need to do a sketch of all your code, deciding what function does what, and putting some functions inside others, for using their scope.